# using a loop get a user to input an integer 10 times then get the minimum

Tags: java, loops, minimum

I've got a homework assignment where I need to write a program using a loop that takes 10 integer values from a user and outputs the minimum of all values entered.

Here is what I've got:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Num52
{
    public static void main (String [] args )
    {

   int value;
   int minValue;

   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

   for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
   {

      System.out.print( "Enter a number as an integer > " );   

      value = scan.nextInt( );

      if( value < minValue )

      minValue = value;

      }

      System.out.println( "The minimum number is " + minValue );


  }
 }
```

Comment: OK. What have you accomplished so far?

Comment: We won't do your homework for you; post what you've tried or researched already.

Comment: sorry, accidentally posted before entering what I had!

Comment: Okay, so what are you having trouble with?

Comment: It keeps saying that minValue hasn't been initialized, but I need to get the minimum value without giving it an initial numerical value like 1000 or something.

Comment: if( value < minValue ) - your minValue is uninitialized. There is nothing to compare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten to initialize minValue.

Try this in your for loop

```
if (i == 0)
    minValue = value;
```

Or you can intialize before for loop like this

```
minValue = Interger.MAX_VALUE; //This is more efficient code.
```

Comment: This is a bad way to code. Since this is just 10 iterations it will be ok. Otherwise it will be a performance hit.

Comment: @StackFlowed could you suggest a better solution then? In your answer you did the exact same thing, and even gave a less-efficient version as well. I think this is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @StackFlowed I doubt that his instructor cares about the performance implications of this statement. There are a ton of other things that introduce WAY more overhead than that. Not even sure why you felt the need to bring it up.

Comment: @jonogilmour If you knew anything about code efficiency you would not say that. Please try running both the code will 10^8 times and see the difference in time. I initialized variable. and I'm not comparing it ever time in the loop.

Comment: @AndySenn using Java is one such piece of overhead. This is obviously a "Learn Java" class, not an algorithms class.

Comment: @StackFlowed I know plenty about code efficiency and I'm saying this answer is fine for the question, there's no need to bring up what happens when you run the for loop 1 billion billion times when the title states "10 integers".

Comment: @StackFlowed You criticised his code and then posted a less efficient version. I see you've deleted that now.

Comment: @StackFlowed No, but you did imply that his solution was intrinsically flawed when you said "This is a bad way to code", which is a pretty arrogant thing to say when it's over something so unbelievably trivial.

Comment: Now can we try to keep the comments constructive, please? @JSS is a first-time poster here, and this sets an incredibly negative precedent.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the efficiency thing. I have updated answer. But just want to say that at the beginning of learning efficiency is not the priority.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone!  I couldn't think of a way to initialize minValue without giving it a specific value.  I'm impressed by the speed and quality of responses that I received!

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize `minValue`, preferably to something high, like `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give your `minValue` an initial value. I suggest [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE). Also, you might use [`Math.min(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min%28int,%20int%29) like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter a number as an integer > ");
        System.out.flush();
        minValue = Math.min(scan.nextInt(), minValue);
    }
    System.out.println("The minimum number is " + minValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `minValue` to some highest value that user will not enter. For better safety, you should initialize to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to start with a correct value for minValaue.We should set it to [MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)

```
public static void main (String [] args )
{    
   int value;
   int minValue=Interger.MAX_VALUE;
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
   {
      System.out.print( "Enter a number as an integer > " );   
      value = scan.nextInt( );
      if( value < minValue ) {
          minValue = value;
      }
   }
   System.out.println( "The minimum number is " + minValue );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( value < minValue )
```

your minValue is uninitialized because it's local. You are comparing value to nothing. If you want to get the default value of an int variable which is 0, make it a global variable. Otherwise, give it your own default value, perhaps Integer.MAX_VALUE as other answers suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize your `minValue` variable with a starting number. Best bet would be to initialize it with `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, like so:

```
int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Also, you should change how you get your integer slightly, to something like:

```
value = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
```